# How to pass array pointer as an argument to the function

Tags: c

There is a struct describing a point in 3D. Triangle can be obviously described as three points. I have to write a function that takes a pointer `point3d *face[3]` and assigns to it an address of the triangle, which was marked during of some operation. How to accomplish that?

```
struct point3d
{ 
   float x;
   float y;
   float z;
};

void copy_address(point3d *face[3])
{
   face = another_address;
}

int main()
{
    point3d *face[3];
    f(&face);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
struct point3d
{ 
   float x;
   float y;
   float z;
};
struct point3d p[3];
void copy_address(struct point3d (**face)[3])
{
   *face = &p;
}

int main()
{
    struct point3d (*face)[3];
    copy_address(&face);
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

Because `face` is a pointer to an array of three points, you need to put braces around it as in `struct point3d (*face)[3];` It means "(`face` is a pointer) to an [array] of 3 points.

You must add the `struct` keyword because `point3d` itself does not identify the type.

In the definition of `copy_address` you need another indirection because you want to assign to the variable that points to the array. It now means "(`face` is the address of a pointer) to an [array] of 3 points.

Comment: I am still gettin error (GCC) expected `‘float *’ but argument is of type ‘float’`

Comment: @Misery, check the line number of error where GCC points to. The error you get is not related to passing array pointer as an argument to the function.